# Getting screen size of android fragment with xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I am currently working on an questionnaire program for android using xamarin and I'm using fragments to display the questions, as there are different question types. I need to make sure there is enough screen space for the questions but unfortunately I can't seem to find anything useful for it or find a version that works with xamarin.

The program is meant to check if there is enough room to draw the question, if there is it draws the question if not then it gets displayed on the next page. The questions are dynamically drawn so the program doesn't know before runtime if there is going to be space or not.

I have managed to get the screen size for the device but when I use similar code for the fragments it returns 0.

This is the code I used for the device and it works fine.

```
Point size = new Point();
this.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetSize(size);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Panel " + size.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have managed to get the screen size for the device but when I use similar code for the fragments it returns 0.

You can get the fragment's size in your fragment like this:

```
public class MyFragment:Fragment
{
    ...

    public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //add global layout event listener
        view.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += ViewTreeObserver_GlobalLayout;
    }

    private void ViewTreeObserver_GlobalLayout(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the size of fragment
        var width=this.View.Width;
        var height = this.View.Height;
    }
}
```